# Run celery with Django start

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, celery-task, djcelery

I am using `Django 1.11` and `Celery 4.0.2`.
We are using a PaaS (OpenShift 3) which runs over `kubernetes` - Dockers.

I am using a `Python` image, it knows only how to run one command on start (and follow for exit code - restart if fails),

How can I run `celery worker` in the same time I am running `Django` to make sure that failure of one of them will kill the both process (worker and Django)

- I am using `wsgi` and `gevent` to start `Django`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use circus ([supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) is an alternative but they don't support python 3 currently)

In circus you create a [circus.ini](https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in your project directory. 
Something like:

```
[watcher:celery]
working_dir = /var/www/your_app
virtualenv = virtualenv
cmd = celery
args = worker --app=your_app --loglevel=DEBUG -E

[watcher:django]
working_dir = /var/www/your_app
virtualenv = virtualenv
cmd = python
args = manage.py runserver
```

Then you start both with:

```
virtualenv/bin/circusd circus.ini
```

It should start both processes. I think this is a good way to create a "start" plan for your project. Maybe you want to add celerybeat or use channels (websockets in django), so you just can add a new watcher in your `circus.ini`. It's pretty dynamic